# Invoke-Command with parameter computername on local device

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm writing a script that needs to be used on multiple devices.
This script uses an `Invoke-command` to connect to a specified server.
This script also has to be run on this same server.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Write-Host "test"}
```

It's no problem to run this script from remote devices but when running it on the server used in `$Server` I get the following error

```
Connecting to remote server DC01 failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (DC01:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken
```

My question is if there is a possibility to fix it or if I have to write an `if/else` to check on which server it's running atm.

Comment: Have you enable powershell remoting on the server?

Comment: Well, I found that when doing research too, I can run invoke-command from other servers to the one I'm trying to run the script on.

When doing `winrm quickconfig` I get

`WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.`

Comment: Powershell remoting uses the winrm service. However you also need to enable powershell remoting. Type Enable-PSremoting in a admin powershell prompt

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it